# Remove domain name from string java

Tags: java, string

I have a string which looks like this

```
String str = "domain\ABC";
String str = "domain1\DEF";
```

How do i write a common function to remove the "domain\" or "domain1\" and just have the string after the the '\'. I tried a couple of different ways but none seem to work.

This is what i have tried.

```
String[] str = remoteUser.split(remoteUser, '\\');
```

Comment: What was the problem with what you tried?

Comment: split returns you an array of strings (tokens). to get what you want just add [1]

Comment: With `String[] str = remoteUser.split(remoteUser, '\\');` you get an array. To get the later part try `System.out.println(str[1]);` as well.

Comment: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 4. ABC\User1. This is the error i get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
String str = "domain\\ABC";
String[] split = str.split("\\\\");

//Assign the second element of the array. This only works if you know for sure that there is only one \ in the string.
String withoutSlash = split[1];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: my string is dynamic here and i am getting it from HttpServletRequest. The String looks like ABC\User1.

Answer (score 6):

No need for `split()` or regex for this, as that is overkill. It's a simple `indexOf()` operation.

> How do i write a common function ... ?

Like this:

```
public static String removeDomain(String input) {
    return input.substring(input.indexOf('/') + 1);
}
```

The code relies on the fact `indexOf()` returns `-1` if `/` is not found, so the `+ 1` will make that `0` and `substring(0)` then returns input string as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `replaceAll`:

```
 System.out.println("domain\\ABC".replaceAll("^.*\\\\",""));
```

It will replace everything starting at the beginning of the string, until `\` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static String getPath(String url) {
    int pos = url.indexOf('\');
    return pos >= 0 ? url.substring(pos + 1) : url;
}
```